# Model only for tests

Tags: django

I want to define model only for using in my test suite. It would be nice, to not create it's table on production. Is there any variable I can test agains to check if I'm in test mode?

Comment: How about defining the model in the actual file (usually tests.py) with the unit tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running your tests using the [Django testing framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/testing/) (`python manage.py test`) then it will automatically create all of the tables for your models in a completely different database, and then populate those tables from your application fixtures, prior to running your tests.  Once the tests have completed, the database will be dropped.  (If your production database is named `foo`, the test database will be named `foo_test`, unless you [specify differently](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/settings/#test-name).)

If you have models that you need only for tests, then all you have to do is to place your test models in the same directory structure as your test code, instead of intermingled with your production models. That will ensure that they are not inadvertently mixed into your production database.

Comment: This is not a valid answer.. "all you have to do is to create the models with your test code"

Answer (score 0):

If you use at recent version of Django(I can confirm versions since 1.4 until 1.6), and uses django.test, you could put all your test models definitions in `tests/__init__.py`. This way, you will have test models in unit tests, without them polluting the production database.